# If same Value Occur Update status as 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like by following..

```
ID  CustId  CustName Status
1     a1       A     NULL
2     a1       A     NULL
3     a2       B     NULL
4     a3       B     NULL
5     a4       C     NULL
6     a4       C     NULL
7     a5       D     NULL
8     a6       E     NULL
```

I want to update the status = 2 when custid occurs 2nd time and I need output following like this...

```
ID  CustId  CustName Status
1     a1       A     1
2     a1       A     2
3     a2       B     1
4     a3       B     1
5     a4       C     1
6     a4       C     2
7     a4       D     2
8     a6       E     1
```

Now I am using the following query to update the status

```
update #tablename
set status= 2
where Custid in
(
  select * from
  (
    select Custid 
    from #tablename
    group by Custid 
    having count(*)> 1
  ) a
)
```

but the above query is updating the status=2 when count(custid)>1
I don't want to update first row..

Comment: MySQL or SQL server both databases use other SQL syntax

Comment: Please show us what you have so far, this is not a code writing service I'm afraid.

Comment: I am using sql server

Comment: I need update statement for this...

Comment: Not accepting an answer to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52361662/update-column-if-countid-have-more-than-one-in-table) and then changing it **much** later to match what you really wanted (i.e. this question) makes me disinclined to even look at this one...

Comment: If same custid occurs more than once need to update status=2 but not for the first time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Column If count(id) have more than one in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52361662/update-column-if-countid-have-more-than-one-in-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #UserCompany
    ([ID] int, [CustId] varchar(2), [CustName] varchar(1), [Status] int)
;

INSERT INTO #UserCompany
    ([ID], [CustId], [CustName], [Status])
VALUES
    (1, 'a1', 'A', null),
    (2, 'a1', 'A', null),
    (3, 'a2', 'B', null),
    (4, 'a3', 'B', null),
    (5, 'a4', 'C', null),
    (6, 'a4', 'C', null),
    (7, 'a4', 'D', null),
    (8, 'a6', 'E', null)
;
select *,row_number() over (partition by [CustId] order by [ID]) as rn from #UserCompany

with cte as 
(
select *,row_number() over (partition by [CustId] order by [ID]) as rn from #UserCompany)
update cte 
set [Status]=case when rn > 1 then 2 else 1 end
```

or

```
UPDATE  b
SET     b.[Status] = a.[Status]
FROM    #UserCompany a
        INNER JOIN (select *,row_number() over (partition by [CustId] order by [ID]) as rn from #UserCompany) b
            ON a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

### Intro

Easiest way to solve this would be with a subquery.

So for every row, you generate a subquery returning only one value.
This subquery will basically count the number of records ( for that customer id), that have an ID >= the current customer id.

### Code

```
UPDATE UserCompany 
SET
      UserCompany.status = temp.status
FROM usercompany AS u
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT ID,
           CustID,
           CustName,

     (SELECT count(*)
      FROM UserCompany t
      WHERE t.custId = u.custId
        AND t.ID <= u.id ) AS status
   FROM UserCompany u ) AS TEMP ON temp.ID = u.ID;

   select * from UserCompany;
```

### Update 1: Only update records where previous same cust instance-count >= 2

```
UPDATE UserCompany 
SET
      UserCompany.status = temp.status
FROM usercompany AS u
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT ID,
           CustID,
           CustName,

     (SELECT count(*)
      FROM UserCompany t
      WHERE t.custId = u.custId
        AND t.ID <= u.id ) AS status
   FROM UserCompany u ) AS TEMP ON temp.ID = u.ID AND TEMP.STATUS >=2;

   select * from UserCompany;
```

### Update 2: Same as Update 1, but set 2 instead of actual count

(same as above but inserts 2 instead of real count)

```
UPDATE UserCompany 
SET
      UserCompany.status = temp.insert_status
FROM usercompany AS u
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT ID,
           CustID,
           CustName,
     2 as insert_status, 
     (SELECT count(*)
      FROM UserCompany t
      WHERE t.custId = u.custId
        AND t.ID <= u.id ) AS status
   FROM UserCompany u ) AS TEMP ON temp.ID = u.ID AND TEMP.STATUS >=2;

   select * from UserCompany;
```

Comment: I need only to update those custid has occurred more than once

Comment: @Rajasekar Baskar , do you only want for 2 or above 2? It's easy to do with a condition. So should we assign 2 if it's grater than 2... I will give you 2-3 examples

Comment: @RajasekarBaskar Updated!